# Error in symmetricds client set up

Tags: database-replication, symmetricds

Unable to set up client which is derby and server is mysql

C:\symmetric-ds-3.0.1-server\symmetric-ds-3.0.1\samples>..\bin\dbimport --engine
     client1 --format XML create_sample.xml
    Log output will be written to ../logs/symmetric.log
    [] - AbstractCommandLauncher - Option: name=engine, value={client1}
    [] - AbstractCommandLauncher - Option: name=format, value={XML}
    [client1] - DerbySymmetricDialect - The DbDialect being used is org.jumpmind.sym
    metric.db.derby.DerbySymmetricDialect
    [client1] - ExtensionPointManager - Found 2 extension points that will be regist
    ered
    [client1] - JdbcSqlTemplate - Table/View 'item_selling_price' already exists in
    Schema 'SYMMETRIC'..  Failed to execute: CREATE TABLE "item_selling_price"
    (
        "price_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
        "price" DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
        "cost" DECIMAL(10,2),
        PRIMARY KEY ("price_id")
    ).
    [client1] - JdbcSqlTemplate - Table/View 'item' already exists in Schema 'SYMMET
    RIC'..  Failed to execute: CREATE TABLE "item"
    (
        "item_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
        "price_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
        "name" VARCHAR(100),
        PRIMARY KEY ("item_id")
    ).
    [client1] - JdbcSqlTemplate - Table/View 'sale_transaction' already exists in Sc
    hema 'SYMMETRIC'..  Failed to execute: CREATE TABLE "sale_transaction"
    (
        "tran_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
        "store" VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
        "workstation" VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
        "day" VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        "seq" INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY ("tran_id")
    ).
    [client1] - JdbcSqlTemplate - Table/View 'sale_return_line_item' already exists
    in Schema 'SYMMETRIC'..  Failed to execute: CREATE TABLE "sale_return_line_item"

```
(
    "tran_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "item_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "price" DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    "quantity" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "returned_quantity" INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY ("tran_id")
).
[client1] - JdbcSqlTemplate - Table/View 'sale_tender_line_item' already exists
in Schema 'SYMMETRIC'..  Failed to execute: CREATE TABLE "sale_tender_line_item"

(
    "tran_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "tender_type" VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
    "tender_amount" DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    "account_number" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("tran_id")
).
[client1] - JdbcSqlTemplate - Constraint 'fk_item_price_id' already exists in Sc
hema 'SYMMETRIC'..  Failed to execute: ALTER TABLE "item"
ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_item_price_id" FOREIGN KEY ("price_id") REFERENCES "item_sell
ing_price" ("price_id").
[client1] - JdbcSqlTemplate - Constraint 'fk_srli_tran_id' already exists in Sch
ema 'SYMMETRIC'..  Failed to execute: ALTER TABLE "sale_return_line_item"
ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_srli_tran_id" FOREIGN KEY ("tran_id") REFERENCES "sale_transa
ction" ("tran_id").
[client1] - JdbcSqlTemplate - Constraint 'fk_srli_item_id' already exists in Sch
ema 'SYMMETRIC'..  Failed to execute: ALTER TABLE "sale_return_line_item"
ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_srli_item_id" FOREIGN KEY ("item_id") REFERENCES "item" ("ite
m_id").
[client1] - JdbcSqlTemplate - Constraint 'fk_tndr_tran_id' already exists in Sch
ema 'SYMMETRIC'..  Failed to execute: ALTER TABLE "sale_tender_line_item"
ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_tndr_tran_id" FOREIGN KEY ("tran_id") REFERENCES "sale_transa
ction" ("tran_id").

C:\symmetric-ds-3.0.1-server\symmetric-ds-3.0.1\samples>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to create the sample tables that are part of the [SymmetricDS Tutorial](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.0/html/tutorial.html) and the tables already exist in the database.  You probably ran the command two times instead of once.  The first time you run it, it creates all the tables.  The second time you run it, it complains that the tables already exist.

I just ran through the tutorial with SymmetricDS 3.0.10 and I got the sample database to replicate between Apache Derby 10.5.3.0_1 and MySQL 5.5.25a.  One thing I noticed is I needed to specify the properties file, like this:

..\bin\dbimport --engine client1 --format XML **--properties client.properties** create_sample.xml

Without specifying the properties file, I thought I was creating tables on the client, but it was still using the server's properties file, which gave me the same error you got.

Comment: You probably called engine in both files the same, and server file was first to find. This command searches for `.properties` files with the engine name you specify in `--engine` clause